# Time-efficient way for creation of many random stick coordinates with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, montecarlo

In a Monte-Carlo simulation I create many lists of random stick coordinates (actually two coordinate lists per repetition representing two different stick types) in the form `[[x0,y0,x1,y1]*N]`. By using vectorized numpy methods I tried minimizing the time of creation. However for certain conditions the length of the arrays goes above 10mio and the generation becomes the bottleneck.

The following code gives a minimum example with some test values

```
import numpy as np

def create_coordinates_vect(dimensions=[1500,2500], length=50, count=12000000, type1_content=0.001):
    # two arrays with random start coordinates in area of dimensions
    x0 = np.random.randint(dimensions[0], size=count)
    y0 = np.random.randint(dimensions[1], size=count)
    # random direction of each stick
    dirrad = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(count)
    # to destinguish between type1 and type2 sticks based on random values
    stick_type = np.random.rand(count)   
    is_type1 = np.zeros_like(stick_type)
    is_type1[stick_type < type1_content] = True
    # calculate end coordinates
    x1 = x0 + np.rint(np.cos(dirrad) * length).astype(np.int32)
    y1 = y0 + np.rint(np.sin(dirrad) * length).astype(np.int32)
    # stack together start and end coordinates
    coordinates = np.vstack((x0, y0, x1, y1)).T.astype(np.int32)
    # split array according to type
    coords_type1 = coordinates[is_type1 == True]
    coords_type2 = coordinates[is_type1 == False]
    return ([coords_type1, coords_type2])

list1, list2 = create_coordinates_vect()
```

The timing analysis gives the following results for the different sections

```
=> x0, y0:                       477.3640632629945 ms
=> dirrad, stick_type:           317.4648284911094 ms
=> is_type1:                      27.3699760437172 ms
=> x1, y1:                      1184.7038269042969 ms
=> vstack:                       189.0783309965234 ms
=> coords_type1, coords_type2:   309.9758625035176 ms
```

I could still gain some time by defining the number of type1 and type2 sticks beforehand instead of doing some random number comparison for each stick. The longer part of creating the random start coordinates and direction plus calculation of the end coordinates would however remain.

Does someone see further optimizations to speed up the creation of the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the timings indicate `x1` & `y1` calculations are the slowest portions of the code. In it, we have `cosine` and `sine` computations, scaling with `length` and then rounding and converting to `int32`. Now, one of the ways people use to boost up NumPy's performance is with [`numexpr`](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) module.

In our slowest portion, the operations that could be computed with `numexpr` are `sine`, `cosine` and the scaling. Thus, the `numexpr` modified version of the code would look like this -

```
import numexpr as ne

x1 = x0 + np.rint(ne.evaluate("cos(dirrad) * length")).astype(np.int32)
y1 = y0 + np.rint(ne.evaluate("sin(dirrad) * length")).astype(np.int32)
```

Runtime test -

Let's consider `(1/100)`th shape to the original array shapes. Thus, we have -

```
dimensions=[15,25]
length=50
count=120000
type1_content=0.001
```

The initial part of the code stays the same -

```
# two arrays with random start coordinates in area of dimensions
x0 = np.random.randint(dimensions[0], size=count)
y0 = np.random.randint(dimensions[1], size=count)

# random direction of each stick
dirrad = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(count)
# to destinguish between type1 and type2 sticks based on random values
stick_type = np.random.rand(count)   
is_type1 = np.zeros_like(stick_type)
is_type1[stick_type < type1_content] = True
```

Next up, we have two brances for runtime testing purposes - One with the original code and another with the proposed `numexpr` based approach -

```
def org_app(x0,y0,dirrad,length):
    x1 = x0 + np.rint(np.cos(dirrad) * length).astype(np.int32)
    y1 = y0 + np.rint(np.sin(dirrad) * length).astype(np.int32)

def new_app(x0,y0,dirrad,length):
    x1 = x0 + np.rint(ne.evaluate("cos(dirrad) * length")).astype(np.int32)
    y1 = y0 + np.rint(ne.evaluate("sin(dirrad) * length")).astype(np.int32)
```

Finally, the runtime test itself -

```
In [149]: %timeit org_app(x0,y0,dirrad,length)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.5 ms per loop

In [150]: %timeit new_app(x0,y0,dirrad,length)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop
```

So, we are looking at about **`40%`** reduction in runtime there, not bad I guess!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about `numexpr` before. Indeed this speeds up the creation of `x1` and `y1` and it was already installed both on Anaconda for Windows and Ubuntu.